# Laravel Routing errors with user permissions

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

New to Laravel and im following along with a book called "Getting Started with Laravel 4" and i ran into a problem with routing.

My Routing file.

```
Route::model('cat', 'Cat');

/**
 * Route: Directs all index.php requests to cats index page
 *
 * @Template index.blade.php
 */
Route::get('/', function()
{
    return Redirect::to('cats');
});

/**
 * Route:
 */
Route::get('cats', function()
{
    $cats = Cat::all();
    return View::make('cats.index')
        ->with('cats', $cats);
});

/**
 * Route: Show cats by category.
 *
 * @Template index.php
 */
Route::get('cats/breeds/{name}', function($name)
{
    $breed = Breed::whereName($name)->with('cats')->first();
    return View::make('cats.index')
        ->with('breed', $breed)
        ->with('cats', $breed->cats);
});

/**
 * Route: Directs the user to the login page.
 *
 * @Template login.blade.php
 */
Route::get('login', function()
{
    return View::make('login');
});

/**
 * Route: Directs users to a single cat object page.
 *
 * @Template single.blade.php
 */
Route::get('cats/{cat}', function(Cat $cat)
{
    return View::make('cats.single')
        ->with('cat', $cat);
});

Route::group(array('before'=>'auth'), function()
{

/**
 * Route: Authenticated route to create a cat in the database.
 *
 * @Template edit.blade.php.
 */
Route::get('cats/create', function()
{
    $cat = new Cat;
    return View::make('cats.edit')
        ->with('cat', $cat)
        ->with('method', 'post');
});

/**
 * Route: Edit cat by specific id.
 *
 * @Template edit.blade.php
 */
Route::get('cats/{cat}/edit', function(Cat $cat)
{
    return View::make('cats.edit')
        ->with('cat', $cat)
        ->with("method", 'put');
});

/**
 * Route: Delete a cat from the database
 *
 * @Template edit.blade.php
 */
Route::get('cats/{cat}/delete', function(Cat $cat)
{
    return View::make('cats.edit')
        ->with('cat', $cat)
        ->with('method', 'delete');
});

/**
 * Route: Updates cat object in database then redirects to cat page.
 *
 * @Template None
 */
Route::put('cats/{cat}', function(Cat $cat)
{
    if(Auth::user()->canEdit($cat)) {
        $cat->update(Input::all());
        return Redirect::to('cats/' . $cat->id)
            ->with('message', 'Successfully updated page!');
    }
    else {
        return Redirect::to('cats/' . $cat->id)
            ->with('error', "Unauthorized operation");
    }
});

/**
 *
 */
Route::post('cats', function()
{
    $cat = Cat::create(Input::all());
    $cat->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    if($cat->save()){
        return Redirect::to('cats/' . $cat->id)
            ->with('message', 'Successfully created profile!');
    }
    else{
        return Redirect::Back()
            ->with('message', 'Could not create profile');
    }
});

/**
 * Route: Deletes cats from database and redirects to cats page
 *
 * @Template: edit.blade.php.
 */
Route::delete('cats/{cat}', function(Cat $cat){
    $cat->delete();
    return Redirect::to('cats')
        ->with('message', 'Successfully deleted page!');
});
});

/**
 * Route: Logs user in or redirects back to previous page.
 *
 * @Template: index.php
 */
Route::post('login', function()
{
    if(Auth::attempt(Input::only('username', 'password'))) {
        return Redirect::intended('/');
    } else {
        return Redirect::back()
            ->withInput()
            ->with('error', "Invalid credentials");
    }
});

/**
 * Route that logs the user out and redirects to index.php.
 */
Route::get('logout', function()
{
    Auth::logout();
    return Redirect::to('/')
        ->with('message', 'You are now logged out');
});

/**
 * Not that sure what this does, Binds cat to a view or something
 */
View::composer('cats.edit', function($view)
{
    $breeds = Breed::all();
    if(count($breeds) > 0){
        $breed_options = array_combine($breeds->lists('id'), $breeds->lists('name'));
    }
    else {
        $breed_options = array(null, 'Unspecified');
    }
    $view->with('breed_options', $breed_options);
});
```

I am trying to route to `http://localhost/cats/public/index.php/cats/create` an d i keep getting the NotFoundHttpException error. I not sure if its because of the order of my routs or what. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should rather test the following url:

```
http://localhost/cats/public/cats/create
```

and not:

```
http://localhost/cats/public/index.php/cats/create
```

I also think (I'm new to Laravel too) that you should move:

```
Route::get('cats/create', function()
{
    $cat = new Cat;
    return View::make('cats.edit')
        ->with('cat', $cat)
        ->with('method', 'post');
});
```

above

```
Route::get('cats/{cat}', function(Cat $cat)
{
    return View::make('cats.single')
        ->with('cat', $cat);
});
```

because the one with `cats/{cat}` and will be always true if url starts with `cats/whatever`

Comment: Thanks broke the route switch worked for me. But a side question is. How do you modify your .htaccess file to not show the index.php?

Comment: By default it shouldn't show index.php in URL but it's quite possible you should rather create virtual host to test your site. Then you could test your site at localhost using url `http://mycatspp/cats/create`